# How can you pass Dictionary to a new Activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

my both key and value needs to be string type

```
Dictionary AccountDetail= new Hashtable();
            AccountDetail.put("PersonName",personName);
            AccountDetail.put("Email",personEmail);
```

But in putString only single value variable is passing and this gives me error

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Maps.class)
.putExtra("AccountDetails" ,AccountDetail));
finish();
```

error says cant resolve method putExtra(java.lang.string.java.util.dictionary)
i can use for loop and and send all elements but if here is method to pass all value at once let me know

Comment: You can pass it as Serializable Extra I guess because Hashtable implements Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you create a new class for your account detail information and then implement [serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable) or [parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) interface. Then you can pass complex data to another activity via Intent.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) instead:

```
Bundle AccountDetail = new Bundle();
AccountDetail.put("PersonName", personName);
AccountDetail.put("Email", personEmail);
```